# opening Flex project without .actionScriptProperties

Tags: apache-flex, flashdevelop

I need to import a flex project into FlashDevelop.
However I am unable to find the .actionScriptProperties file. 
How would I be able to import the project?

It would be great if someone could help me out with it.

Comment: Is this not your third question on the topic in the past 24 hours?  By "Flex Project" do you mean an actual Flash Builder project, or something different?  In a Flash Builder project, the property files should be in the eclipse workspace directory.

Comment: yeah..this is the first time I am working on it and I have no clue about it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually Flex Builder project contains:

src/ directory - source files (.as and .mxml)

libs/ directory - .swc files (if exists)

Usually FlashDevelop project contains:

1) src/ directory - place here files from src directory of FB project

2) lib/ directory - place here .swc files (if exists) from libs directory of FB project

3) on each swc files (if exists) you need make right click and select "Add to Library".

4) Make right click on main class file and select "Document Class"

This is main. May be there are other files. But I can not say what you have because I not know what files you have.

Comment: This is the first time I am working on this. so I dont have much of an idea on what to do. previously I had imported a project by just opening the .actionScriptProperties file or the .as3proj file. The project I am trying to import has neither.. so I am stumped

Answer (score 1):

actually i can´t import a FB project to FD whit the options in the menus but i can fix it creating a new project in the folder of the FB project and putting files in folders identified by FD it works for me

Comment: Have you checked to see if this overwrites any pre-existing information in the original project files?